# Are the exponential and matrix exponential valid over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{F}$?

Tags: matrices, field-theory, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

I understand that if $[A] \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ then the matrix exponential of $[A]$ is denoted $e^{[A]} \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, and is defined by
$$e^{[A]} := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} [A]^k$$
and that this is a generalization of $e^x: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. I wanted to know if we can say that $e^x: \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$ for some field $\mathbb{F}$, and if the matrix exponential would then be well-defined.

Comment: For an arbitrary field, it doesn't make sense to add infinitely many elements. You'll need to equip your field with some extra data (for example, a topology) in order to talk about convergence of infinite sums.

Comment: If $\Bbb F$ has characteristic $p > 0$, then the terms of the sum with $k \geq p$ are not even defined

Comment: Try the simplest cases: $\mathbb F = \mathbf Q$ and $\mathbb F = \mathbf Z/(p)$ for prime $p$.  Either one will give you an answer.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of why this is @Stahl ?

Comment: @user129393192 I don't have an example; infinite sums simply aren't defined unless you have a notion of convergence (remember that addition is by definition only a binary operation $k\times k\to k$). In $\Bbb{C},$ we say that $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_i$ is defined to be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$ if the limit exists. It may be illuminating for you to let $k$ be an arbitrary field, let $a_1, a_2,\dots$ be a sequence of elements in $k,$ and then try to write down a definition for $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_i$ using only the field axioms.

Comment: Are you saying that, for something like $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$, that it could be either 0 or 1, so it is undefined?

Comment: Not quite. Say you have a sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ of elements in $\Bbb{F}_p.$ In the usual definition of limit, we talk about absolute values, and the only reasonable "absolute value" on $\Bbb{F}_p$ is the one which sets $|a|=1$ if $a\neq0$ and $|0|=0.$ Then mimicking the definition of limit from analysis will tell you that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$ if and only if $a_m=L$ for all $m$ sufficiently large. This means the only infinite sums which will exist are the ones of the form $a_1+\dots+a_n +0+0+0+\dots$ which are really just finite sums, since eventually you're just adding $0$'s.

Comment: I don’t quite get it. What is wrong with it becoming a finite sum, and couldn’t an element be either 0 or 1 in something like $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: @user129393192 There's nothing "wrong" with having a finite sum, it just means that the situations in which the exponential would converge would be very limited. Additionally, as Travis Willse pointed out, for $\Bbb{F}_p,$ most of the terms in the exponential won't even be defined, since $p = 0$ and having anything larger than $(p-1)!$ will cause division by $0$ problems.

Comment: Here's perhaps another way to look at my original comment of needing a topology on your field. Beyond the fact that infinite sums are not defined for fields without topology, a field could have multiple natural topological structures. For example, $\Bbb{Q}$ has one topology for each prime $p$ (the $p$-adic topology) and the Euclidean topology. An infinite sum which converges in one topology need not converge in another, and will change what you can plug into your exponential (or possibly even if it ever converges).

Comment: As an example, the sum $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty p^i$ converges in the completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ with respect to the $p$-adic topology, but diverges with respect to the Euclidean topology.